# Variavel Calendar não é reconhecida pelo android

Tags: android

Estou a declarar assim no meu projecto e não consegue reconhecer a variavel calendar **"Cannot resolve symbol 'Calendar'"**

```
Calendar calendario= new Calendar.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Não use ***new***, afinal getInstance é um método estático.